# Spring's InitializingBean, CommandLineRunner, ApplicationContextEvent and javax's PostConstruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-framework-beans

This question is about the behavioural differences between Spring's

- InitializingBean's `afterPropertiesSet()`
- CommandLineRunner's `init()`
- `ApplicationContextEvent` and
- javax's `@PostConstruct`

For `@PostConstruct` it guarantees that it will be executed one and only once after the target bean has been fully loaded with required dependencies, reason being , if we go by custom logic from within constructor the Spring bean is not yet fully initialized and might throw `NullPointerExceptions`. Does this handles any circular dependencies?

Does `InitializingBean` guarantees the same? How is it different from `@PostConstruct`? Does InitializingBean provides any ordering?

Suppose in my app, I need to check if some test-users are there in database or not, if not app should create it on startup or logging the env variables. Where should these process should ideally be written into?

For `ApplicationContextEvent`, Spring says, "raising an event on ApplicationContext startup or refresh" but how is it different from `@PostConstruct` and `org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner#run`.

Also, how will these behave in case of 'hot' swap or refresh?